# Import Header-File depending on the target name in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor

I have a preprocessor constant called TARGET_NAME holding the current target name. I want to import a certain header file depending on the target name, e.g. include "App-Config.h" when TARGET_NAME is set to App-Config. How am I going to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use

```
#if TARGET_NAME == yourtargetname
#import "App-Config.h"
#endif
```

I have not used this yet but assuming your target's name is in TARGET_NAME this should work